are "day by day" and "by the day" the same?
The dictionary says "His health is growing worse day by day. = His health is growing worse by the day. [=his health is growing worse every day]"
However, Chat GPT says "day by day" emphasizes the gradual increment while "by the day"  infers the rapid increment.
Similarly, "Her English improves month by month" vs "Her English improves by the month"
"it happened minute by minute" vs "it happened by the minute" etc

Why are you more inclined to believe Chat GPT than an authoritative dictionary?

@KateBunting Sometimes even the best dictionaries are wrong -- I've found errors in OED, MW, and just yesterday in Britannica. When that happens, ChatGPT is likely to be right, as in this case.

"X by X" and "by the X" apply to different things, and with different focuses.
X by X can apply to any process, and indicates slow and steady progress. The focus is on how steady and perhaps inevitable the progress is.
by the X more narrowly applies only to processes of change, and indicates rapid change. The focus is on how fast the change is happening, so it often indicates urgency.
So, Britannica is wrong to say those sentences are equivalent. I've sent them a notice.
As for "It happened...", if it's not clear from the context that "it" is a change, then only "minute by minute" can apply. "... by the minute" is an error.

I'm not so sure that by the X necessarily indicates change that is rapid. Consider He plodded along, growing wearier by the mile.

@PaulTanenbaum If he's moving slowly, then yes each mile takes a long time, but the use of "by the mile" means he's growing weary faster than in , "growing wearier mile by mile".
